# Tooltipster does not expand when dynamically generate content for it

Tags: jquery, html, tooltipster

In my project I show a tooltip using tooltipster when user hover on element that with class "tooltip". Because of there is too much of element with class "tooltip", I decided to generate the content for tooltip when user hover on the element like below:

```
function onHover(e) {
    ...
    var content = "<img id='cropImg' style='width:250px;' src='....'/>";
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster('content', content);
}
```

Tooltipster initialization:

```
$('.tooltip').tooltipster({
   theme: 'tooltipster-noir',
   side: 'bottom',
   delay: 300,
   maxWidth: 450,
   minWidth: 250,
   contentAsHTML: 'true'
});
```

The problem is when it show the tooltip the content is not fully shown, it always have a scrollbar on the tooltip. It will fully shown when i hover on the same element second time. Anybody know how to solve this? Sorry for my bad english...

[image]

Comment: Why using hover event handler to show tooltip, isn't tooltip supposed to kickin automatically on hover?

Comment: @Viney that function is to change the content of the tooltip..

Comment: That's to be expected if you put an image which is asynchronously loaded, read the FAQ in the documentation and check available options.